# as400 session shows à instead of @ in email addresses

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a user that logs into his session, but when he goes to view the email address on system, on his screen à appears instead of @ in all email addresses?

IS THIS A system issue or pc issue?

he is on a french laptop, with french keyboard, keyboard for session is 'French 187' which is his layout, I just wondered why this à character shows instead of @

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a code page inconsistency between what is believed by the remote system and what is believed by the green screen software (Client Access).

You need to find out if the @ is correctly represented on the remote system (i.e. entered incorrectly) or not.